# Ionic native Transfer plugin's `file.dataDirectory` shows error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm going to use [**the Ionic native Transfer plugin**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/) as shown below.
Problem is here `this.file.dataDirectory`.It shows error like `[ts] Property 'dataDirectory' does not exist on type 'File'.`.Can you tell me what is the solution for this?

```js
download() {
        const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
        const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
        fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
            console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        }, (error) => {
            // handle error
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.. My bad :(

I have to install [**File plugin**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) too :D

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```